# Excluding IDs with some value day after day

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
ID      Date    X   Y
 A  16-07-19  123  56
 A  17-07-19  456  84
 A  18-07-19    0  58
 A  19-07-19  123  81
 B  19-07-19  456  70
 B  21-07-19  789  46
 B  22-07-19    0  19
 B  23-07-19    0  91
 C  14-07-19    0  86
 C  16-07-19  456  91
 C  17-07-19  456  86
 C  18-07-19    0  41
 C  19-07-19  456  26
 C  20-07-19  456  17
 D  06-07-19  789  98
 D  08-07-19  789  90
 D  09-07-19    0  94
```

I want to exclude IDs that have any value in `X` column **(except for `0`)** day after day.

For example: `A` has the value `123` on `16-07-19`, and `456` on `17-07-19`. So all `A`'s observations should be excluded.

Expected result:

```
ID      Date    X   Y
 B  19-07-19  456  70
 B  21-07-19  789  46
 B  22-07-19    0  19
 B  23-07-19    0  91
 D  06-07-19  789  98
 D  08-07-19  789  90
 D  09-07-19    0  94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this in a vectorized manner, to keep our code as efficient as possible
(meaning: we avoid using `GroupBy.apply`)

1. First we check if the difference in `Date` is `equal` to 1 day
2. We check if `X` column is `not equal` to `0`
3. we create a temporary column `m` where we check if both conditions are `True`
4. We `groupby` on `ID` and remove all groups where `any` of the rows are `True`

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  <- if Date is not datetime type

m1 = df['Date'].diff(1).eq(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
m2 = df['X'].ne(0)

df['m'] = m1&m2

df = df[~df.groupby('ID')['m'].transform('any')].drop(columns='m')

   ID       Date    X   Y
4   B 2019-07-19  456  70
5   B 2019-07-21  789  46
6   B 2019-07-22  0    19
7   B 2019-07-23  0    91
14  D 2019-06-07  789  98
15  D 2019-08-07  789  90
16  D 2019-09-07  0    94
```